# Use kermit through terminal-server from python

Tags: python, pexpect, terminal-server, kermit

I would like to use `kermit` through terminal server from a `Python` code. I tried to solve it with `pexpect` module but after the spawn it logs out with EOF so the child is dead.

```
    child = pexpect.spawn('echo os.environ["MODULESHOME"]/init/sh; module add kermit; kermit kermit-vpp.kermit -- ' + target + ' ' + port)
    child.maxread=1000

    i = child.expect_exact(['-----------', 'U-Boot', pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT], timeout=20)
    print child.before
    if i == 1:
        print '****Timeout'
        sys.exit(1)
    if i == 2:
        print '****Eof'
        sys.exit(1)
```

Is there any idea to solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't your `if i == 1` line be `if i == 3`? Timeout is the third entry in your list.

Comment: ...I mean, the fourth entry. Which is `l[3]`, because of 0-based indexing.

Comment: Yoy are right, but it does not change anything.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're passing multiple commands separated by `;`. `spawn` expects a single command. Is there a single command way to start it? Or you could spawn a shell using `sh -c` and then run multiple commands.